# grails: select like numeric up down

Tags: grails, gsp, numericupdown

I've searched around the net but I have not found a solution.
Is there something like numeric up down, for numeric selection in Grails?
How can I create it?

Comment: This is purely html/js not really Grails my man.

Comment: @marko I've only asked if there is some tag in Grails that creates it...if not, I will surely use pure HTML/JS for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement via simple html as:

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity">
```

you can set range also as:

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

and If you want you can add value attribute to be shown as:

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" value="${domainInstace.attribute}">
```

and Enjoy.......

Comment: but how to link this <input> tag with domain class instance that owns the numeric value?

Comment: The input tag allows me to enter also characters...I need that only numeric values could be entered.

Comment: I've read about input tag with "number" that allows to see a spinner with HTML5...in Firefox it is not shown, but in Chrome it works...I need something that is useful for both browsers

Answer (score -1):

Within a gsp ?

```
<g:select id="orderby" name="orderby" from="${1..10}"  noSelection="['':'-Define Display Order 1 top 10 bottom-']" required="" value="${youdomainClassInstance?.orderby}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

Comment: do this select has the two arrows to manage the value or is it a classic gsp select?

Comment: ye it be the classic where you choose from dropdown